# Calling Javascript function from Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I've an Android Webview project that needs to access some Javascript functions. I've set up everything as per [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) tutorial. And everything works, I can load html from Android app, can call Android class methods from Javascript as per the method described in the tutorial.

There's one thing which I can't make work and that is calling a Javascript function from Java class in Android. The Javascript function just prints a log message for test.

My index.html includes sample.js. Here's sample.js file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function init(event) {
       function foo(){
          console.log("javascript foo() function called from android");
       }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

}());

function foo1(){
   console.log("javascript foo1() function called from android");
}
```

And calling from Java Webview:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:foo1()"); //this works
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:foo()");  //this gives error
```

As you notice, I've created 2 foo functions in Javascript files and they are placed differently. Calling foo1() works but calling foo() shows this error in logcat:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined: Line 1 of file:///android_asset/index.html
```

I suspect that is because foo() is inside the anonymous function.

Can anyone show me how can I call foo() from Android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**foo** and **foo1** functions have different scope. That's why **foo** is not available.
To be able to call **foo** you can add this function to **window** object. See below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function init(event) {
       window.foo = function() {
          console.log("javascript foo() function called from android");
       }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

}());

function foo1(){
   console.log("javascript foo1() function called from android");
}
```

So **foo** function added directly to window object and it have the same scope as **foo1**.